# How to commit an svn propset from the CLI?

Tags: svn

I am using SVN on a project and after creating a `.svnignore` file, I have told SVN about it:

```bash
svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .
```

How can I commit that propset from the command-line interface (CLI)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read SVN Book about [svn properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html), understand that `svn ps` (in any form) just change *something* in your WC, thus, if you want to save these new properties from your modified WC (check `svn st` output) you have just commit.

**Extending by commands**

After `svn ps` you'll get some changed in your WC, easy discoverable with [`svn st`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html), which you have to commit into repository as any other changes with [`svn ci -m "<SOME DESCRIPTIVE COMMIT MESSAGE>"`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html)

Comment: Thanks for that reference!  Research and reading are fundamental... But I was hoping for something more along the lines of *here is the actual CLI command to type into your bash terminal, e.g. `svn do --magic`* ?